# why function gives me back wrong number?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, reference

Write and test your own functions in the program:

1. `int function1 (const char * string1, const char * string2)`
   compares two strings lexicographically, returning
   0 if the strings are identical, -1 if string1 is earlier than string2, +1 if string1 is later,
   e.g. `function1 ("cca" , "abcd")` `-> 1`, `function1 ("abcde", "b")` `-> -1`
2. `int function2 (const char * string)`
   returning the number of unique digits appearing in the string,
   e.g. `function2 ("ab512af6kc1") -> 3`.

   ```
   int main() {
       cout << cmp("abc","a") << endl;
   }
   int cmp(const char* string1, const char* string2) {

       for(int i = 0; i < len(string1); i++) {

           if (i == len(string1)) {
               return 0;
           } else if (string1 > string2) {
               return 1;
           } else if (string1 < string2) {
               return -1;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

It returns me -1 but should 1 because "abc" is later in dictionary than "a".

What about second exercise? i have no idea how to start with it.

Comment: You are comparing the pointers, use `strcmp`

Comment: i have to write OWN function instead of strcmp... so i cant use it

Comment: You can use `std::string::compare`, or study its source if you can't directly use it.

Comment: It'd be better if you re-read your C++ book and realise `string1` and `string2` are pointers and their comparison makes no sense here.

Answer (score 0):

As I posted in the comments, you should go back and re-read your c++ book. `string1` and `string2` are pointers and you shouldn't be comparing them here.

Here's a working solution  for problem 1:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

int cmp(const char* string1, const char* string2) {
    int n1 = std::strlen(string1);
    int n2 = std::strlen(string2);
    int i=0;
    while (i<n1 && i<n2)
    {
        if (string1[i] < string2[i]) return -1;
        else if (string1[i] > string2[i]) return 1;
        else i++;
    }
    if (n1 == n2) return 0;
    if (i == n1) return -1;
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << cmp("a","abc") << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

For the second problem, you can go about it by keeping the count of characters using a hashmap.

Answer (score 0):

[**Live sample of both exercises**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/kbP7N7u2i8PR8jjc)

For **Exercise 1**, I believe the goal is to make a function similar to `strcmp()`, so it's not the size that matters but the lexicographical order, so what you should do is to compare each character, so for instance `cmp("abcd", "abce")` should be `-1` and `cmp("abce", "abcd")` or `cmp("abe", "ab")` should be `1`:

```
int cmp(const char* string1, const char* string2) {

    do{
       if(*string1 > *string2){  //because of ASCII codes you can compare characters like this
           return 1;
       }
       if(*string1 < *string2){
           return -1;
       }      
    } while(*string1++ && *string2++); //while none of the chars is null

    return 0;  //reached if no different chars were found so the strings are equal
}
```

For **Exercise 2** you can extract digits to a different container, sort and compare them:

```
int function2 (const char * str){

    vector<int> digits; //dynamic container since the digit count is unknown at first
    int count = 0;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)  //extract digits from string
        if(str[i] >= '0' && str[i] <= '9')
             digits.push_back(str[i] - '0'); //add to digit container

    sort(digits.begin(), digits.end()); //sort digit vector

    for(size_t i = 0; i < digits.size() - 1; i++){ //compare digits and count if no repeat
        if(digits[i] != digits[i + 1] && digits[i + 1] != digits[i + 2]){
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Libraries

```
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
```